# "Clearly conflicts with the author's intent" vs "Attempt to reply"

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

I'm confused about the usage of two default Rejected Edit messages:

[image: rejected edit messages]

I often reject an edit for *clearly conflicts with the author's intent*, and then I realize one or two other users flagged it for *attempt to reply*. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15533649) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15535765).

If a user is adding information to an answer that is technically unrelated to the original content of the answer, which rejection message should I use? For example, if a user adds something like:

> You can also try `FOO-ING X` if `BAR Y` is available.

It clearly conflicts with the author's content, but it *also* should hvae been written as a comment or an answer (per the *attempt to reply*'s description).

Which should I use? Can I use either? Should the two be merged into one? Should we edit the descriptions? This has bothered me ever since I've been able to review suggested edits.

Comment: Many people use "attempt to reply" because the recommendation to post a new answer is more helpful to the editor if they see the rejection message. If the edit would work better as its own answer or as a comment, I choose "attempt to reply", otherwise I choose "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

Comment: Its a bit drastic to merge or edit descriptions because you found an edit which just happens to go both ways - its not exactly uncommon, but not the norm either. There are plenty of occasions where only one of the two clearly applies, the descriptions are specific enough.

Comment: In both of those cases, I'd definitely have gone with "attempt to reply"; they're adding information, not removing/changing/contradicting what was already there.